# Drupal 8 cron not running from external source (as anonymous)

Tags: 8, cron

Running cron with crontab is not working on our Drupal 8 website if the user is anonymous. If I'm logged in as admin, I can run cron with the button or the url with key. If I'm not logged in, cron doesn't run with url with key.

Running from crontab is of course anonymous and so cron is not running.

Any ideas?

Version: Drupal 8 beta 4

Line in crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.entityone.be/nl/cron/theactualcronkeyhere
```

Comment: anything in the drupal log messages ?

Comment: No, nothing in the logs. Not even an access denied.

Comment: Are you invoking cron via cURL, wget, Drush? Did you check /var/log/daemon.log and does it report anything related to your cron job here? Did you read https://www.drupal.org/node/23714 and did it help?

Comment: @anavarre I added the line in crontab to the question. I'm using wget. I did read http://drupal.org/node/23714, but nothing helpful for this issue. I don't have access to /var/log/daemon.log, only to the apache logs. It may be worth mentioning another cron for Drupal 7 is running on the same server successfully.

Comment: Do you see anything in the apache access log? What happens if you explicitly provide a wrong cron key? No reason that shouldn't work

Comment: HTTP/1.1" 204 381 "-" "Mozilla/5.0... when going to the url as authenticated user in the browser. And HTTP/1.1" 204 402 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu) when running in cron

Comment: With the wrong key I get 'You are not authorized to access this page.' As expected.

Comment: Maybe remove the language from the url?

Comment: I tried with and without language prefix, no luck.

Comment: How do you know cron is not running? That 204 suspiciously looks like as if it would be running: `CronRunTest::testCronRun` asserts exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old, but I faced a similar problem and would like to help people coming from google.

I assume you have a function in one of your specific cron hooks which needs extra permissions to run which won't work because Drupal runs cron as an anonymous user.

What helps is to identify which hook_cron needs elevated rights and switch to e.g. the admin account before the affected code runs:

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\UserSession;

// call the account switcher service
$accountSwitcher = \Drupal::service('account_switcher');
// switch to the admin user
$accountSwitcher->switchTo(new UserSession(['uid' => 1]));

// run your code here

// switch back to old session
$accountSwitcher->switchBack();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use following line and it works pretty well on drupal 8.0.5

```
wget -q http://domain/cron/theactualcronkeyhere -O /dev/null
```